# How do I blacklist certain applications in OSX programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, blacklist

I am trying to develop some software similar to selfcontrol (it blacklists certain websites for a certain amount of time). However, I want to be able to do this with applications on OSX (for example, a person would have to answer some math questions before accessing the MineCraft App).

Is there some sort of parental control API in the OSX SDK? I'm familiar with some kernel development, but I'm just looking for a starting point of where to look.

Comment: The title says that you want to blacklist applications while you says you want to blacklist web sites with your application.

Comment: No, I was giving an example of an existing application: selfcontrol prevents you from accessing websites so you can be more productive. What I want is a way to blacklist applications in a synonymous manner.

Answer (score 1):

System preferences does include parental control options. Search for `com.apple.familycontrols` to find options for how you can interact with the available settings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any high level API that allows you to do this.

However, as you state you're familiar with Kernel development, that's the way to go and indeed it's how the parental controls work; with a kernel extension (kext).

[This article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html) explains about 4 scopes of interest for authorization in the kernel. You'll need to write a kernel extension and monitor the VNode scope, which will inform your kext of all vnode access by calling a function defined in your kext. This function must then return one of either Accept, Deny or Defer. If you call Deny on access to a vNode that is making an Execute operation, then it will be blocked.

Finally, if you're going to write any kernel code, then I recommend you get a copy of [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542), which includes example code based around monitoring the vnode scope.